# Should Tag Manager's snippet be officially entered into the head or body?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Google Analytics' https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080 states:

> Paste your snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) into every web page you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing  tag.

But what about Tag Manager? Is there an **updated official** documentation about whether it should be in the head or body (and where exactly in the head/body)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Pechou, turns out there's also https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696

> **Adding the Container Snippet**
>
> Paste this code so that it appears immediately after the opening <body> tag on every page on your site.

Comment: I added a quote, but please realize this is **both** a standalone reply **and** a comment (which I also referred to in a proper comment). It provides a general public version (as opposed to a developer one) of a reply to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is ... https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart
Just after the body opening.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the regular support version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29974370/4829915

Answer (score 0):

The snippet needs to be placed just after the opening  tag and not within any other tag such as a div so that it is most compatible with all browser types and versions.